# Python unexpected indent in query

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I have been trying to query Postgres via Python(2.7). I found this tutorial, however, this code:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='student' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='password'")

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT * from table1""")
```

gives me

```
   cur.execute("""SELECT * from table1""")
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I have no idea why. Please help.

Comment: You may have some extra space or tab in your code

Comment: Thanks, that was it. However, now it tells me the relation table1 does not exist, although I know exactly, that it does